# Spinnaker UI security(Oauth2.0) with Azure kubernetes throws error

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have installed Spinnaker on azure kubernetes (inside docker container) and accessing spinnaker UI with external public IP and port (configured 2 load balancers)

http://externalIP:9000.

I am trying to configure the OAuth2.0 for spinnaker UI. following this link 
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/oauth/

steps done:

in Azure, created client secret, client id , passed redirect url as http://externalIP:9000

On spinnaker ,configured and enabled Oauth with following steps

```
CLIENT_ID=myClientId
CLIENT_SECRET=myClientSecret
PROVIDER=google|github|azure

hal config security authn oauth2 edit 
–client-id $CLIENT_ID 
–client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET 
–provider $PROVIDER
hal config security authn oauth2 enable
```

Now if I try to access the spinnaker UI http://externalIP:9000. and see access logs in chrome browser, it says user not found.

What more configuration is required?

should able to access spinnaker UI and it should ask for login

Answer (score 0):

yeah the problem is that you must choose a specific provider then apply the configs.

```
CLIENT_ID="myClientId"
CLIENT_SECRET="myClientSecret"
PROVIDER="azure"

hal config security authn oauth2 edit 
–client-id $CLIENT_ID 
–client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET 
–provider $PROVIDER
hal config security authn oauth2 enable
hal deploy apply
```

Then it should work. Check the logs.